# How to get Pinterest Total Share Count Using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pinterest

What i require? I need to get a total share count using javascript.

Using this link: https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=http://google.com

I can get the result:
`receiveCount({"url":"http://google.com","count":11278})`

My code which is not working, i'm not sure which part of the code is wrong. Below:

```css
#pin-div {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="pin-div">0</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var url = "http://facebook.com";
    var apiUrl = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=" + url;

    $.ajax({
      url: apiUrl,
      success: function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(key, val) {
          console.log(key + " - " + val["receiveCount"]["count"]);
          var shareCount = val["receiveCount"]["count"];
          $("#pin-div").html(shareCount);
        });
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Why is this tagged PHP?

Answer (score 5):

Your data is [jsonp](/questions/tagged/jsonp): `receiveCount({"url":"http://google.com","count":11278})`. Where the `receiveCount` function must be created in the window context to hold the data.

You need to add: `dataType: "jsonp"` in your `$.ajax` code.

You can try with this version of your code:

```css
#pin-div {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

<div id="pin-div">0</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    var url = "http://facebook.com";
    var apiUrl = "https://api.pinterest.com/v1/urls/count.json?callback=receiveCount&url=" + url;

    $.ajax({
      url: apiUrl,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function(result) {
        receiveCount(result);
      }
    });
  });

  function receiveCount(data) {
    $("#pin-div").html(data.count);
  }
</script>
```